# Cannot import localization in Xcode Couldn't Communicate with a helper application

Tags: xcode, localization

I am using macOS High Sierra (beta) and xCode 9 (beta) and trying to work with localization. Anytime I try to import a localized .xliff I get an error that states: Couldn't communicate with a helper application. Try your operation again. If that fails, quit and relaunch the application and try again.

I have done everything I can think of. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localization using Apple's provided tools tends to go wrong much more often than it goes right. As far as my applications are concerned, I don't use these tools at all. That goes for any project where I'm using anything more complicated than the default localization function with default parameters:

```
NSLocalizedString("this is a key but also a string I guess")
```

Trying to do anything even slightly more cohesive:

```
NSLocalizedString("this_is_a_key", value: "This is a string", comment: "This tells the translator useful stuff")
```

ends up breaking the `genstrings` program and creating a whole other mess. I've taken to manually updating string resource files and using a third party or in-house script to generate other files (any `.strings` files for example). It may add a bit of arguably unnecessary human touch to the string generation process, though I don't find this to be problematic since it increases visibility of how strings work between the resource and application code.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I will look into that and see if I use something like that.